# Is there any way to join two data frames by date ranges?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two data frames, the first dataset is the record for forecasted demand in the following 27 days for each item of the company, shown as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

daily_forecast <- data.frame(
  item=c("A","B","A","B"),
  date_fcsted=c("2020-8-1","2020-8-1","2020-8-15","2020-8-15"),
  fcsted_qty=c(100,200,200,100)
) %>% 
  mutate(date_fcsted=ymd(date_fcsted)) %>% 
  mutate(extended_date=date_fcsted+days(27))
```

and the other dateset is the actual daily demand for each item:

```
actual_orders <- data.frame(
  order_date=rep(seq(ymd("2020-8-3"),ymd("2020-9-15"),by = "1 week"),2),
  item=rep(c("A","B"),7),
  order_qty=round(rnorm(n=14,mean=50,sd=10),0)
)
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to get the actual total demand for each item within the **date_fcsted** and **extended_date** in the first dataset and then have them joined to calculate the forecast accuracy.

Solutions with *tidyverse* would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `fuzzyjoin` package does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try `fuzzy_join` as suggested by @Gregor Thomas. I added a row number column to make sure you have unique rows independent of `item` and date ranges (but this may not be needed).

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

daily_forecast %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(actual_orders,
                  by = c("item" = "item",
                         "date_fcsted" = "order_date",
                         "extended_date" = "order_date"),
                  match_fun = list(`==`, `<=`, `>=`)) %>%
  group_by(rn, item.x, date_fcsted, extended_date, fcsted_qty) %>%
  summarise(actual_total_demand = sum(order_qty))
```

**Output**

```
     rn item.x date_fcsted extended_date fcsted_qty actual_total_demand
  <int> <chr>  <date>      <date>             <dbl>               <dbl>
1     1 A      2020-08-01  2020-08-28           100                 221
2     2 B      2020-08-01  2020-08-28           200                 219
3     3 A      2020-08-15  2020-09-11           200                 212
4     4 B      2020-08-15  2020-09-11           100                 216
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for your help and I was trying with fuzzy_join as well. But it constantly gave me the error messages and now with your code, i understand what i did wrong. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

daily_forecast %>%
  left_join(actual_orders, by = 'item') %>%
  filter(order_date >= date_fcsted & order_date <= extended_date) %>%
  group_by(item, date_fcsted, extended_date, fcsted_qty) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(order_qty))

#  item  date_fcsted extended_date fcsted_qty value
#  <chr> <date>      <date>             <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A     2020-08-01  2020-08-28           100   179
#2 A     2020-08-15  2020-09-11           200   148
#3 B     2020-08-01  2020-08-28           200   190
#4 B     2020-08-15  2020-09-11           100   197
```

Comment: Hi Roak, thank you so much for your quick reply and it is a brilliant solution! Thank you!